# Sorting integer array to avoid repeating consecutive values in C

Tags: c, linux, sorting, int

I'm using Linux to implement this sorting. If I have a array `arr[] ={1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}`, how to sort it by this:

```
arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 3
arr[3] = 1
arr[4] = 2
arr[5] = 3
arr[6] = 1
```

I Tried to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
  if (arr[i] < arr[i+1])
  {

  }
}
```

Please give me some suggestions, thank you so much!

Comment: Is there anything you've tried? Please share your attempts.

Comment: How would you sort `{1,1,1,2,2,3,4}` ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Output should be {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1}

Comment: @CoolGuy I tried to use if-else statement, but I don't know how to start it. Hope you can give an idea.

Answer (score 0):

a hint

first you have to sort the array, then starting from 1 to (end-1) if active item equals to the last item move it to the end.

Comment: That doesn't guarantee no consecutive duplicates.

Comment: take a look at the code i submitted (UP). just to keep things simple

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*__________________________________________________
*/
static int __cdecl sortCallback(int *i1,int *i2){
    return (*i1<*i2)?-1:(*i1>*i2)?1:0;
}
/*__________________________________________________
*/

void printArr(char* Title,int *arr,int n){
    int i;
    if(Title)
        printf("%s:\n\t",Title);

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return;
}
/*__________________________________________________
*/
void arrange(int *arr,int n){
    int i=1,j;
    int a;
    while(i<(n-1)){
        if(arr[i]==arr[i-1]){
            a=arr[i];
            for(j=i;j<(n+1);j++){
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
            }
            arr[n-1]=a;
        }else
        i++;
    }
}
/*__________________________________________________
*/
int main(void){
    int arr[7];
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    arr[2] = 3;
    arr[3] = 1;
    arr[4] = 2;
    arr[5] = 3;
    arr[6] = 1;
    printArr("Initial",arr,7);
    qsort(arr,7,sizeof(int),sortCallback);
    printArr("Sorted",arr,7);

    arrange(arr,7);
    printArr("Rearranged",arr,7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Linux to implement it, but sortCallback cannot identify on this case.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cnv(int n, int arr[n]){//arr is sorted
    struct {
        int value;
        int occurs;
    } tmp[n];

    //make distinct array
    int k = 0;
    tmp[k].value = arr[0];
    tmp[k].occurs = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i){
        if(arr[i] != arr[i-1]){
            tmp[++k].value = arr[i];
            tmp[k].occurs = 1;
        } else {
            ++tmp[k].occurs;
        }
    }
    //Written back
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; ++i){
        while(tmp[j].occurs == 0){
            j = (j == k) ? 0 : j + 1;
        }
        arr[i] =  tmp[j].value;
        --tmp[j].occurs;
        j = (j == k) ? 0 : j + 1;
    }
}

int main(void){
    int arr[] ={1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    cnv(n, arr);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```